# Windows Phone 8 API for Headset control events

Tags: c#, api, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, headset

Is there an API for Windows Phone 8 which allows to receive headset events, such as when a user presses the play/stop button? I would be interested in these events to react in my application accordingly.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in control of the audio/video on the device at this point (via `MediaElement` or `BackgroundAudioPlayer`), then play/pause events will be raised in your code via `MediaElement` or `BackgroundAudioPlayer`.

If you are not in control of the audio/video, then it is not possible to capture these events.

Comment: I need the event outside of a MediaElement to control other functions. So it seems not supported. Thanks anyway!