# Detect Media Button Click Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I realize that this thread may be closed or flagged but I have a query and havent been able to find a definitive answer. I also dont have the tech to test out myself.

We have an Android application that uses a background service to detect if the media button on the attached headphones (or attached media input device) is pressed.

All I need to know if is it possible to detect this type of event on Windows Phone?

Some background. We are not playing any media we are simply hooking into the MediaService in Android and handle events when the media button is pressed.

Any link to a credible resource, code snippet or anything where I can definitivly say "Yes it is possible" will be accepted.

Comment: not sure if that's what you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607626/windows-phone-8-api-for-headset-control-events

Comment: have you tried adding a key event listener to your app to see if something comes up?

Comment: @thumbmunkeys I appreciate the link but actually unless you have the hardware (which I don't currently have) I can't actually testing the media button. That being said from the link provided it appears as if it is not possible unless our app is responsible for the media playing. As stated in the OP we aren't playing any media just waiting for the button to be pressed. Thanks for your help.